# How can I hide an uncaught error from my browser?

Tags: javascript

I have some simple code that does the job but gives an uncaught error.

```
 ck.setMode('source');
 ck.setMode( 'wysiwyg');
```

This is giving me the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

I know it's probably a bad practice but the error does not cause any problems and I would like to avoid it showing in the browser. Is there some way that I could enclose this code so it does not give a browser console alert?

Here's the code that encloses the above:

```
ngModel.$render = function () {
    if (typeof ngModel.$modelValue != 'undefined') {
        if (ngModel.$modelValue != null) {
            ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
             timer = setTimeout(function () {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
             }, 1000);
             timer = setTimeout(function () {
                 ck.setMode('source');
                 ck.setMode('wysiwyg');
             }, 1000);
        }   
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you use `try` and `catch` to catch the error?

Comment: Why don't you fix the bug in the `setMode()` function?

Comment: It's a ckEditor function. I've been looking at this for 12 hours now and still cannot see what's making the problem :-(

Comment: Try tracing the stack to find the piece of code that triggered the error. You may be missing a library, or you could be loading scripts in the wrong order...

Comment: I tried but everything points to a minimized version of ckEditor. I have asked a friend to post on the ckEditor tag for help. Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

You may use code like this:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {  
    // maybe some handling?  
    return true; // prevents browser error messages  
};
```

It prevents all error messages, so use it with care.

Comment: I added some more code. The problem is inside of an Angular directive from ckEditor.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code block inside a try catch. So your code would become like this.

```
try {
   ck.setMode('source');
   ck.setMode( 'wysiwyg'); 
}
catch (error) {
   // handle your error
}
```

Comment: +1 Way better to put try/catch blocks as close to the offending code as possible rather than catch everything at a very high level.